# Stopping when the solution is good enough?

Tags: optaplanner, quarkus

I successfully implemented a solver that fits my needs. However, I need to run the solver on 1500+ different "problems" at 0:00 precisely, everyday. Because my web-app is in ruby, I built a quarkus "micro-service" that takes the data, calculate a solution and return it to my main app.

In my application.properties, I set:

```
quarkus.optaplanner.solver.termination.spent-limit=5s
```

which means each request take ~5s to solve. But sending 1500 requests at once will saturate the CPU on my machine.

Is there a way to tell OptaPlanner to stop when the solution is good enough ? ( for example if the score is stable ... ). That way I can maybe reduce the time from 5s to 1-2s depending on the problem?

What are your recommandations for my specific scenario?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.41.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#termination) . Also you may want to look here for [batch processing](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.41.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#solverManagerSolveBatch) .

Comment: @k88 Thank you! It's exactly what I was looking for. Can't believe I missed this whole part of the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SolverManager will automatically queue solver jobs if too many come in, based on its `parallelSolverCount` configuration:

```
quarkus.optaplanner.solver-manager.parallel-solver-count=3
```

In this case, it will run 3 solvers in parallel. So if 7 datasets come in, it will solve 3 of them and the other 4 later, as the earlier solvers terminate. However if you use `moveThreadCount=2`, then each solver uses at least 2 cpu cores, so you're using at least 6 CPU cores.

By default `parallelSolverCount` is currently set to half your CPU cores (it currently ignores moveThreadCount). In containers, it's important to use JDK 11+: the CPU count of the container is often different than from the bare metal machine.

---

You can indeed tell the OptaPlanner Solvers to stop when the solution is good enough, for example when a certain score is attained or the score hasn't improved in an amount of time, or combinations thereof. [See these OptaPlanner docs.](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#termination) Quarkus exposes some of these already (the rest currently still need a solverConfig.xml file), some Quarkus examples:

```
quarkus.optaplanner.solver.termination.spent-limit=5s
quarkus.optaplanner.solver.termination.unimproved-spent-limit=2s
quarkus.optaplanner.solver.termination.best-score-limit=0hard/-1000soft
```